# Getting error when creatign app using create T3

Tags: typescript

I'm creating an app using `npm create t3-app@latest` and once i cd into the project and run `npm run dev` i run into a weird error:

```
npm run dev             

> accumulator@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

(node:29350) ExperimentalWarning: stream/web is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/Users/mm/localCode/projects/accumulator/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/request.js:28
class NextRequest extends Request {
                         ^

ReferenceError: Request is not defined
   at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mm/localCode/projects/accumulator/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/request.js:28:27)
   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
   at Module.mod.require (/Users/mm/localCode/projects/accumulator/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:64:28)
   at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mm/localCode/projects/accumulator/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/adapters/next-request.js:37:18)
   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

not sure what is causing this i've tried to updating the dependencies but that didn't do it, any suggestions on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @radu tarean said it had something to do with my node version being an old version of node.

However when I ran `sudo n latest` I got something like this:

```
copying : node/21.2.0
   installed : v21.2.0 to /usr/local/bin/node
      active : v16.11.1 at /Users/mm/.asdf/installs/nodejs/16.11.1/bin/node
```

this is indicating that the latest version wasn't active on my computer

**To fix this you should:**

1. Run `asdf list nodejs` to list all node versions on your computer
2. Then run `asdf global nodejs <node_version>` to set it to active

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue comes from using an old version of node. Try running node --version to see your version. If you are using version 16 or lower, try upgrading your node version because the latest `create-t3-app` node engine requirement is,

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=18.17.0"
},
```